# Why would we want to define new types in a functional programming language?

Tags: type-theory

I am a total noob to programming, and one of the basic ideas in Haskell is how one can define new types using some things called constructors. I haven't quite understood it fully, but why would one want to make any types beyond the basic ones? What practical utility does it hold?

Comment: For one, it is a good way to organize your data logically so that the code is more readable and maintainable by giving you a decent level of abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

If you write a banking system, you will have entities representing users, accounts, transactions, balances, money, … If you write a game, you will have entities representing players, levels, maps, enemies, NPCs, weapons, vehicles, … If you write a media player, you will have entities representing albums, tracks, artists, …

Without the ability to define your own types for all of those entities, the language would have to ship with every single type that every single programmer could possibly need for every single program that will ever be written … including types for concepts that don't even exist yet!

You can see how it is much more convenient to allow the programmer to define their own types than to try and predict the needs of every programmer who will ever be born.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have to use a data type multiple times in multiple functions ,one way is to use the primitive data types again and again ,Other way is to use type synonyms to gove the desirred name to the primitive type.That's  ehere the idea of custom type comes in to give a name to a data type composed of multiple primitive data types and to define operations on those types using structyural induction.Example-

```
type Sentence = String
wordList Sentence= spllitat ' ' Sentence
``
```